# OpenGL ES draw bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es

I am making an Android app to take photos and use filters. Filters are provided by android.media.effect package. To use the filters, I have to draw the bitmap on a GL surface.

When I draw it, the bitmap is cropped.
The first screenshot is when I take the photo. The second is when I draw it on the surface.

[image: When I take the photo]

[image: When I draw it to the surface]

I don't know a lot about OpenGl, but I've spent a lot of time to search the problem, and I still have no solution.
I put my code below and I cross my fingers, maybe someone have the solution.

Thank you very much for reading.

The entry of the intent :

```
public class PhotoEditor extends AppCompatActivity {

private GLSurfaceView surface;
private Bitmap bmp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_editor);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + i.getStringExtra("photo_uri"));

    try {
        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("photoapp", "Impossible de charger la photo.");

        return;
    }

    surface = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glSurface);;
    surface.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    surface.setRenderer(new EffectsRenderer(this, bmp));
    surface.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}}
```

The renderer :

```
public class EffectsRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private Bitmap bmp;
private int width, height;

private int textures[] = new int[2];
private Square square;

private EffectContext effectContext;
private Effect effect;

public EffectsRenderer(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    super();
    this.bmp = bmp;
    width = bmp.getWidth();
    height = bmp.getHeight();
    Log.d("photoapp", "width : " + width);
    Log.d("photoapp", "height : " + height);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width, height);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    generateSquare();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if(null == effectContext) {
        effectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
    }

    if(null != effect){
        effect.release();
    }

    grayScaleEffect();

    square.draw(textures[1]);
}

private void grayScaleEffect(){
    EffectFactory factory = effectContext.getFactory();
    effect = factory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
    effect.apply(textures[0], width, height, textures[1]);
}

private void generateSquare(){
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
    square = new Square();
}}
```

The square class :

```
public class Square {

private float[] vertices = {
        -1f, -1f,
        1f, -1f,
        -1f, 1f,
        1f, 1f
};

private float[] textureVertices = {
        0f, 1f,
        1f, 1f,
        0f, 0f,
        1f, 0f
};

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;" +
                "attribute vec2 aTexPosition;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_Position = aPosition;" +
                "  vTexPosition = aTexPosition;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D uTexture;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPosition);" +
                "}";

private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

private int vertexShader;
private int fragmentShader;
private int program;

public Square() {
    initializeBuffers();
    initializeProgram();
}

private void initializeBuffers() {
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    buff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    verticesBuffer = buff.asFloatBuffer();
    verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
    verticesBuffer.position(0);

    buff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureVertices.length * 4);
    buff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = buff.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(textureVertices);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
}

private void initializeProgram() {
    vertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    fragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
}

public void draw(int texture) {
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

    int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
    int textureHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uTexture");
    int texturePositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aTexPosition");

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(texturePositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, textureBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texturePositionHandle);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, verticesBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}}
```

Comment: The surface that you are rendering into is the same size as the screen size. Image size is larger than the surface area and hence it is cropped. 
You need to create an offscreen FBO which has the same size as the image, then render onto the offscreen FBO and use the offscreen FBO texture as the final output.